# using CMake to complie cause SGX_ERROR_UNEXPECTED?

Tags: makefile, cmake, sgx

I am trying to learn intel sgx sdk recently.

Today i found a problem in my code and can not find any explain in intel DOC or WEB.

The code will return SGX_ERROR_UNEXPECTED when i call sgx_create_enclave in some situations. I think there are something wrong in my CMakeLists.txt( I use cmake to compile the untrusted part in my project), because code run correctly when i use the template Makefile in sdk example to compile. More details blow:

code will run success under these situations:

```
  * compile with Makefile

  * compile with cmake and comment out app.cpp:21
```

code will return error under this situation:

```
  * compile with cmake and do not comment out app.cpp:21
```

**code available here (i have remove all unnecessary code):**  https://github.com/chilogen/workspace/tree/master/error/SimpleEnclave

**app.cpp**

```
#include "enclave_u.h"
#include <sgx_urts.h>
#include <sgx_uae_service.h>
#include <sgx_ukey_exchange.h>
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;

class testClass {
public:
      sgx_launch_token_t _token = {0};
      sgx_enclave_id_t _eid;
      sgx_ra_context_t _ctx;
      void init_enclave();
      bool request(uint8_t *src, uint32_t srcLen, uint8_t *cmac);
      //will set _ctx here
      //void do_attestation();
}x;

bool testClass::request(uint8_t *src, uint32_t srcLen, uint8_t *cmac) {
    sgx_status_t retval,status;
    status = ecall_calcmac(_eid, &retval,&_ctx, SGX_RA_KEY_SK, src, srcLen, cmac);
    return true;
}

void testClass::init_enclave(){
    sgx_enclave_id_t global_eid;
    sgx_launch_token_t token={0};
    sgx_status_t ret;
    int updated=0;
    ret=sgx_create_enclave("enclave.signed.so",SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, \
                        &token,&updated,&global_eid,NULL);

    if(ret!=SGX_SUCCESS){
        std::cout<<"error init enclavedsfdsf\n";
        printf("%08x\n",ret);
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(){
    x.init_enclave();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
include_directories (/opt/intel/sgxsdk/include)
link_directories (/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64)
add_library (enclave_untrusted enclave_u.c)
add_executable (app app.cpp)
target_link_libraries (app enclave_untrusted sgx_ukey_exchange sgx_urts sgx_uae_service pthread)
```

**Makefile** (I think this is important part, if you don't know well at intel sgx, than you can still examine the different between CMakeLists.txt and Makefile)

## SGX SDK Settings

```
SGX_SDK ?= /opt/intel/sgxsdk

SGX_LIBRARY_PATH := $(SGX_SDK)/lib64
SGX_ENCLAVE_SIGNER := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x64/sgx_sign
SGX_EDGER8R := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x64/sgx_edger8r

######## App Settings ########

App_Include_Paths := -I$(SGX_SDK)/include 

App_Link_Flags := -L /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64 -lsgx_urts -lsgx_ukey_exchange -lsgx_uae_service  -pthread 


.PHONY: all
all: app

######## App Objects ########

enclave_u.c: $(SGX_EDGER8R) enclave.edl
    @$(SGX_EDGER8R) --untrusted enclave.edl --search-path $(SGX_SDK)/include
    @echo "GEN  =>  $@"

enclave_u.o: enclave_u.c
    @$(CC) $(App_Include_Paths) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "CC   <=  $<"

app.o: app.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(App_Include_Paths) -c $< -o $@ 
    @echo "CXX  <=  $<"

app: app.o enclave_u.o
    @$(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(App_Link_Flags)
    @echo "LINK =>  $@"

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @rm -f *.o app
```

**update : compile.sh**

```
gcc -c -I /opt/intel/sgxsdk/include/ -o enclave_u.o enclave_u.c

g++ -c  app.cpp -o app.o -I /opt/intel/sgxsdk/include/

g++ -o app app.o enclave_u.o -L /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64 -lsgx_urts -lsgx_ukey_exchange -lsgx_uae_service  -pthread
```

So, what is wrong in my code (or CMakeLists.txt), how should i do?

I will be so thankful if your get me some idea about it.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want to have the code **in the question post**, *links* are insufficient for that purpose. Please, add the code into the question post. (You may provide link to your repo too, but all important part of the code should be in the question post).

Comment: OK, thanks, I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the target based API instead of the directory based:

```
add_library (enclave_untrusted enclave_u.c)
add_executable (app app.cpp)

target_include_directories (enclave_untrusted PUBLIC /opt/intel/sgxsdk/include)

target_link_libraries (enclave_untrusted PUBLIC
    "/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_urts.a"
    "/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_ukey_exchange.a"
    "/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_uae_service.a"
)
target_link_libraries (app PRIVATE enclave_untrusted pthread)
```

But I would advise using an appropriated CMake library, like  [SGX-CMake](https://github.com/zhang-xin/SGX-CMake)

Comment: also the same problem for this CMakeLists.txt , i am going to try SGX-CMake

Comment: it work for [SGX-CMake](https://github.com/zhang-xin/SGX-CMake). I will upload my new CMakeLists.txt and solutions next day. Thank you 
Guillaume Racicot.

Comment: I also renew my post on intel forum and signed your name for this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem still seems strange. I can fix the example here by using SGX-CMAKE, but it seems not work for my project in this morning. However, after do lots of tries (and i don't know which is the key), it work for my project now. I will keep searching for the key behind all of these and update here if i find one.

For now, i will upload the CMakeLists.txt for the example above if anyone need it.

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PATH_TO_FindSGX.cmake_FILE})
find_package(SGX REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-fpie -fPIC -fstack-protector -g -O2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpie -fPIC -fstack-protector -g -std=c++11 -O2 -DDEBUG -UNDEBUG -UEDEBUG")


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(EDL_SEARCH_PATHS .)

set(E_SRCS enclave.c)
set(LDS Enclave_debug.lds)


add_enclave_library(enclave SRCS ${E_SRCS} EDL enclave.edl EDL_SEARCH_PATHS            
                    ${EDL_SEARCH_PATHS} LDSCRIPT ${LDS})
enclave_sign(enclave KEY Enclave_private.pem CONFIG Enclave.config.xml)

set(SRCS app.cpp)
add_untrusted_executable(app SRCS ${SRCS} EDL enclave.edl EDL_SEARCH_PATHS   
                         ${EDL_SEARCH_PATHS})
```